# Is there a a way to embed a forum into a mobile app using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, embed, forum

I'm building a mobile app and one of the features it has is a forum, I was wondering if there is a way to embed one into the app.

e.g If I make a free forum using any website that offers it, is it possible to embed it in an app?

I'm using HTML/CSS with Javascript/Jquery

Edit: Not a java question.

Comment: Please provide moire details of your app like Android or IOS?

Comment: if you don't care it enough to implement in the app, can you just include a link to the forum and open it in a browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I embed a website in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869152/how-can-i-embed-a-website-in-my-app)

Comment: It's based on Javascript/ Jquery so Android or iOS doesn't matter @elegant-user .

Comment: @cwang I'm just asking the question if its possible. Why would I build a whole forum if it is possible to do in another way

Comment: @ShreeKhanal That topic is more Java based, mine is javascript

Comment: This might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069283/1225070